No me funciona los estilos de los botones de PrimeNG con angular 17
Estoy utilizando primeNG con Angular 17, y al querer usar los botones no se ven de la misma forma que en primeNG
mi forma:

como deberia verse:

tengo en mis styles:
  @import "primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-purple/theme.css";
@import "primeng/resources/primeng.css";
@import "primeicons/primeicons.css";

en mi app.component.ts:
  imports: [RouterOutlet, SharedModule, CommonModule,],

en mi app.config.ts:
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes),provideAnimations(), provideHttpClient(withFetch())]
};

no puedo usar los botones rounded
alguna solucion?
Nota:
ya encontre el tema, es porque estoy incluyendo el CND de bootstrap porque cuando lo quito ya me muestra bien los botones
pero no se que hacer

Si quieres usar las opciones de boostrap para manipular y organizar (columnas, filas, etc) el CSS puedes usar PrimeFlex

Debes declarar en tu angular.json los estilos de primeng:
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/erp",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "browser": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
        "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
        "styles": ["src/styles.scss", "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"],
        "scripts": []
      },

